# Netbeans plugins site is down rendering netbeans useless

Tags: plugins, netbeans

I'm using Netbeans 11.1 and need to a open a JS file in my project.

I need to install the Oracle JS Parser for Netbeans which I cannot do so because the site - plugins.netbeans.org is down. I'm getting this error -

> Networking problem in
> http://plugins.netbeans.org/nbpluginportal/files/nbms/1552395301_org-netbeans-libs-oracle-jsparser.nbm

Is there anyway I can install it manually otherwise I cannot resume work with netbeans rendering it useless.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are encountering was a bug in the released version of NetBeans 11.1. See Bug Report [NETBEANS-2903](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-2903) *Warning - could not install some modules: Nashorn Integration - No module providing the capability com.oracle.js.parser.implementation could be found. 19 further modules could not be installed due to the above problems*.

You have two options to fix this:

- Upgrade to NetBeans 11.2 or later, where the problem does not exist.
- Download and install the plugin yourself on NetBeans 11.1 by going to **Tools > Plugins >** then clicking the **Settings** tab, then the **Add** button. In the **Update Center Customizer** window enter any descriptive text in the **Name** field, in the **URL** field enter https://netbeans.apache.org/nb/plugins/11.1/catalog.xml.gz and then click **OK**. However, I just tried that, and got the error "*Unable to connect ... because of Unexpected end of file from server*". That connection may come good at any time, or it may be that you can no longer reliably access the plugin libraries for older versions of NetBeans.

So your only immediate solution is to [upgrade to any newer version of NetBeans](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb123/nb123.html). That's desirable anyway, because you will get other bug fixes as well as this one. And if you move to NetBeans 12.x you will also get added functionality, and be able to use more recent versions of the JDK.

Also, as a separate but related matter, you were using an **http** URL rather than an **https** URL for your download. I'm not certain, but I doubt if that will work now; if you are not using a secure link you should expect failure, and in any case it looks like you were using a URL for NetBeans 8 rather than NetBeans 11.